# How to test whether org-narrow-to-subtree is in effect

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to include a limiting statement in a function that tests whether the buffer has already narrowed to the subtree after having used `org-narrow-to-subtree`. Can anyone please share with me how to test whether the narrowing condition is in effect?  Something like `narrowp`.

---

**EDIT**:   I found the test here:  https://raw.github.com/ptrv/org2blog/org-8-support/org2blog.el

Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://raw.github.com/ptrv/org2blog/org-8-support/org2blog.el

```
(defun narrow-p ()
  "Return t if a buffer is narrowed"
   (not (equal (- (point-max) (point-min)) (buffer-size))))
```

Comment: This is a very general test. The result is non-nil for any narrowing.